# How to move a simple React JS app from the root into a subdirectory?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

We received a simple app from an over-seas developer. This application runs on a subdomain: 
IE: https://balance-sheet.clientdomain.com/

We have access to the files, but when we try and move the files into a subdirectory: 
IE: https://www.clientdomain.com/balance-sheet/ 
Then the application does not run any more.

We have tried to edit several of the javascript files to reference the new location to address the errors that were being produced. However even after the errors were fixed the app still does not run.

I have lots of dev experience, but none with the React JS stuff. Do we need original files to re-deploy? Is it possible to edit the current files to make this work?

This project is so simple, it is a basic balance sheet for training purposes.

Below is a screenshot of the app and then the file-system.

Should I provide any links or files of the actual project?

I'm really just first trying to get a feel for the options here...

Thanks all!

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Add `<base href="/subdir/">` in the head section of index.html and change subdir to your sub directory name. Please refer this [link](https://skryvets.com/blog/2018/09/20/an-elegant-solution-of-deploying-react-app-into-a-subdirectory/)

Comment: Hello and thank you for your input! Very much appreciated!

Comment: The base was added to the head and I can confirm that all the files are loading properly. But the app comes up blank. I feel like I am either way off base in trying to move this app or I am completely missing something.